# Can we move the RAID array from one HP Server models to another HP models or one RAID controller model to another Controller model

Tags: hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, server-setup

In case my HP Proliant DL380 G6 & G7 failed, can I swap all HDD to HP Proliant DL380 G9.

HP Proliant DL380 G7 is using the different controller (HP Smart Array Controllers P410i) and HP Proliant DL380 G9 is using different controller (HP Smart Array Controllers P440ar)

Please help to resolve this confusion

Comment: I've done that with LSI-based RAID. I moved from old Dell PERC into more modern LSI MegaRAID; it worked flawlessly. In HP case, chances are high that it would work if you shutdown server, move disks and then power on new server. But I strongly suggest you to check that beforehands, to do so create a dummy array, shutdown server, move disks and see if other server recognises the array.

Comment: in case you don't care about anything why not, setup a new raid format the disk and start from scratch ;)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same situation, did you by any chance try it in the past 10 months and are able to answer your own question?